# Django Bootstrap Integration

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

Well I'm trying to use Bootstrap with Django by copying and pasting the folders from Bootstrap to static folder. But I'm not able to get access to the Bootstrap.css file. It shows `404` error.

Just for experimenting purpose, I created a `main.css` in the static/css folder and linked it in the template and to my surprise, its running.
So, why the bootstrap.css file is not getting linked.

Here is how I'm linking Bootstrap.css in my template

```
{% block css %} 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/bootstrap.css">
{% endblock %}
```

Here is my root **urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                            (r'^',include('apps.home.urls')),
                            (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root':os.path.normpath( os.path.join( os.path.dirname(__file__),'../static/'))}),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

`MEDIA_ROOT = 'C:/Users/Praful/uploads'`

`MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`

`STATIC_ROOT = ''`

`STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

Answer (score 2):

You should try this instead:

```
{% load static %}

{% block css %} 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css ' %}">
{% endblock %}
```

...and just make sure you have 'django.contrib.staticfiles' in your `INSTALLED_APPS`. Please see also https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#template-tags

(EDIT: fixed typo, I oroginally forgot the "static" keyword)

OR this:

```
{% block css %} 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{STATIC_URL}}css/bootstrap.css">
{% endblock %}
```

..assuming "django.core.context_processors.media" is in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`

Comment: It not working. the 2nd part of your solution was tried earlier by me but unfortunately, didnt worked

Comment: oops, I lost the "static" part, please see the updated answer

Comment: My main question is why the main.css, the file that i included in the css folder for testing is getting linked but not bootstrap.css. Why>?

Comment: R u sure the relative path to bootstrap.css is corrent? This is crazy! :)

Comment: Yes. It is correct. Even I am going crazy about this. This is weird.

Comment: Seems like I have to style it on my own in the main.css only. :(

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [faststart-bootstrap](https://bitbucket.org/aselivanov/faststart-bootstrap) Django project skeleton with Bootstrap 3 support. However it's based on [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) style sheets, but LESS is easy to learn (in use) and compatible with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

ok, that's a settings and path problem.

First, put that in your settings:

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__name__))

MEDIA_ROOT = os.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'uploads')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

And that in your template

```
{% block css %} 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}/css/bootstrap.css">
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: My main question is why the main.css, the file that i included in the css folder for testing is getting linked but not bootstrap.css. Why>?

Answer (score 0):

Check your project structure. I follow this structure:

```
/Project_name
  /App1
  /App2
  /App3
  /Project_name
  /media
  /static
     /css
        bootstrap.min.css
     /js
  /templates

/Requirements
  requirement.txt

.gitignore
```

With this structure and a proper settings and template files shown by [lalo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17958039/django-bootstrap-integration#answer-17958157), bootstrap should be work without 404.